# What is the symbol that “the watcher” has in WandaVision?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision

The *WandaVision* TV series takes place in some unknown reality (to me at least having not seen any material outside the show). At the end of the first episode we see that an unknown individual is watching the two through an old CRT screen alongside some more modern devices. A circular symbol with a sword through it can be seen on the notebook and the modern screen.

[image]

**What is this symbol? What does it belong to?**

Comment: It belongs to someone who really wanted their acronym to spell the word SWORD.

Comment: @Valorum: a member of A.R.M.S (Acronym, Retronym, Moniker and Sobriquet)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By the looks of it, it is most likely a reference to the [Sentient World Observation and Response Department](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Sentient_World_Observation_and_Response_Department_(Earth-616)).

> S.W.O.R.D. (an acronym for Sentient World Observation and Response Department) was a counter terrorism and intelligence agency which dealt with extraterrestrial threats to world security. S.W.O.R.D. was a subdivision of S.H.I.E.L.D. but appeared to be largely autonomous of its parent organization. Since the departure of Nick Fury as director of S.H.I.E.L.D., relations between the two organizations became strained.

In the MCU, the acronym instead stands for **S**entient ***W**eapon* **O**bservation and **R**esponse **D**ivision.

[image: SWORD logo]

Comment: Or Sentient __Weapon__ Observation and Response Department

Answer (score 3):

In **MCU** the symbol stands for

> **S.W.O.R.D.** (an acronym for **S**entient **W**eapon **O**bservation and **R**esponse **D**ivision)

[image: S.W.O.R.D. Logo]

and is an <strike>organization that replaced **S.H.I.E.L.D** to protect the Earth from threats</strike> American intelligence agency.<sup>[1](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/S.W.O.R.D.)</sup>

Comment: Regarding the last comment, whilst that is likely true, especially given what we see  at the end of _Far From Home_ there is no confirmation of this as of yet is there? That fan written wiki appears to grab straight from the comics. Note the more accurate wiki is [this one](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/S.W.O.R.D.) which doesn't state that.